# Fragment onResume() & onPause() is not called on backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, back-stack

I have multiple fragment inside an activity. On a button click I am starting a new fragment, adding it to backstack. I naturally expected the `onPause()` method of current Fragment and `onResume()` of new Fragment to be called. Well it is not happening.

### LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      final View view  =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
      final FragmentManager mFragmentmanager =  getFragmentManager();

      Button btnHome  = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
      btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
           HomeFragment fragment    = new HomeFragment();
           FragmentTransaction ft2   =  mFragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
           ft2.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_out_left
                    , R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
           ft2.replace(R.id.middle_fragment, fragment);
           ft2.addToBackStack(""); 
           ft2.commit();    
         }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
     Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of LoginFragment");
     super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause of loginFragment");
    super.onPause();
  }
}
```

### HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     final View view  =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
     Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of HomeFragment");
     super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
     Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause of HomeFragment");
     super.onPause();
  }
}
```

What I expected, was,

1. When button is clicked, **LoginFragment** gets replaced with
   **HomeFragment**, `onPause()` of **LoginFragment**, and `onResume()` of
   **HomeFragment** gets called
2. When back is pressed, **HomeFragment** is poped out and **LoginFragment** is
   seen, and `onPause()` of **HomeFragment** and `onResume()` of **LoginFragment**
   gets called.

What I am getting is,

1. When button is clicked, **HomeFragment** is correctly replacing
   **LoginFragment**, onResume() of **HomeFragment** is called, but onPause()
   of **LoginFragment** is never called.
2. When back pressed, **HomeFragment** is correctly popping to reveal
   **LoginFragment**, onPause() of **HomeFragment** gets called, but onResume()
   of **LoginFragment** never gets called.

Is this the normal behaviour? Why is `onResume()` of **LoginFragment** not getting called when I press the back button.

Comment: Add the activity code that handles the fragments.

Comment: i'm having the sample problem, on pause not get called, how did you resolve this,

Comment: I had the same problem but realised i was using ft2.add(); instead of ft2.replace(). Only other reason would be if your activity is keeping a reference to the fragment (adding it to a collection, or assigning it to a class variable)

Comment: I am having the same problem. I noticed that .replace() will call the necessary lifecycle methods, but it essentially destroys the fragment. Also, onSaveInstanceState is *not* called. As such, I cannot keep its state. So, I need to use add, but the onResume/Pause is not called :(

Comment: FWIW, my experience is that support library fragments do call onPause and onResume when pushing/popping backstack, but the Android built-in fragments do not.  Haven't found a proper workaround for that yet.

Comment: why do you inflate login_fragment in the home fragment? is that a typing mistake?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Ya it was a typo. I tried to clean up the code base (removing some un important contents) before posting here. I no longer has access to this code (This question was asked 6 years ago). But I remember I got this working that day.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The fragments `onResume()` or `onPause()` will be called only when the Activities `onResume()` or `onPause()` is called.
They are tightly coupled to the `Activity`.

Read the [Handling the Fragment Lifecycle section of this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: In the article, it is said that "once the activity reaches the resumed state, you can freely add and remove fragments to the activity. Thus, only while the activity is in the resumed state can the lifecycle of a fragment change independently." Does this mean that the fragment onResume can be called even if the activity onResume is not called ?

Comment: as for native (not support) fragments in 4.4 (not sure if it's true for older versions) onPause() and onResume() are called not only when these events occur in the activity, but for example when you call replace() or add()/remove() while performing transaction, so this answer is misleading at least for the recent versions of Android.

Comment: According to that document, the fragment should actually be moved to the stopped state when swapped out into the backstack.  But not only are onPause and onResume not getting called, neither are onStop and onStart -- or for that matter, any other lifecycle methods.  So the guide is definitely misleading.

Comment: Although not related but I found this question while searching for my problem of `onPause()` getting called after `onSaveInstanceState()` instead of before it. This can be reproduced if you to a different child in my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (say you move from child 0 to child 2, **note to self, this happens because child 0 is destroyed when child 2 opens**)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Calling ft.replace should trigger the onPause (of the replaced fragment) and onResume (of the replacing fragment). This is done regardless of any activity...

Comment: I can confirm that this effect does not exist in the latest Android 9.0. The fragment::onResume() get invoked when popped up from the backstack. I can also confirm that we had this issue before, about 3/4 years ago.

Answer (score 23):

- Since you have used `ft2.replace()`, `FragmentTransaction.remove()`
  method is called and the `Loginfragment` will be removed. 
  Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29). 
  So `onStop()` of `LoginFragment` will be called instead of `onPause()`. (As the new
  fragment completely replaces the old one).
- But since you have also
  used `ft2.addtobackstack()`, the state of the `Loginfragment` will be
  saved as a bundle and when you click back button from `HomeFragment`,
  `onViewStateRestored()` will be called followed by `onStart()` of
  `LoginFragment`. So eventually `onResume()` won't be called.

Comment: `onViewStateRestored` is called if you have `setRetainInstance(true)`

Comment: and `setRetainInstance` is currently deprecated in favor of the viewModel pattern :/

Answer (score 18):

Here's my more robust version of Gor's answer (using fragments.size()is unreliable due to size not being decremented after fragment is popped)

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getFragmentManager() != null) {

                Fragment topFrag = NavigationHelper.getCurrentTopFragment(getFragmentManager());

                if (topFrag != null) {
                    if (topFrag instanceof YourFragment) {
                        //This fragment is being shown. 
                    } else {
                        //Navigating away from this fragment. 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And the 'getCurrentTopFragment' method:

```
public static Fragment getCurrentTopFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
    int stackCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (stackCount > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(stackCount-1);
        return  fm.findFragmentByTag(backEntry.getName());
    } else {
        List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
        if (fragments != null && fragments.size()>0) {
            for (Fragment f: fragments) {
                if (f != null && !f.isHidden()) {
                    return f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you really want to replace fragment inside other fragment you should use [Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

In your code you should replace

```
final FragmentManager mFragmentmanager =  getFragmentManager();
```

with

```
final FragmentManager mFragmentmanager =  getChildFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            List<Fragment> fragments = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
            if (fragments.size() > 0 && fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1) instanceof YoureFragment){
                //todo if fragment visible
            } else {
                //todo if fragment invisible
            }

        }
    });
```

but be careful if more than one fragment visible

Comment: Thanks, it works, but if only one fragment is visible (so, `ViewPager` with fragments will reference to its fragments).

Answer (score 4):

I have a code very similar to yours and if it works onPause () and onResume (). When changing the fragment, these functions are activated respectively.

Code in fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, proximidad, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, brillo, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    Log.e("Frontales","resume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    Log.e("Frontales","Pause");

}
```

Log when change of fragment:

```
05-19 22:28:54.284 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: resume
05-19 22:28:57.002 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: Pause
05-19 22:28:58.697 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: resume
05-19 22:29:00.840 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: Pause
05-19 22:29:02.248 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: resume
05-19 22:29:03.718 2371-2371/madi.cajaherramientas E/Frontales: Pause
```

Fragment onCreateView:

```
View rootView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_proximidad, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView);
    inflar();
    setTextos();
    return rootView;
}
```

Action when I pulse back (in the activity where I load the fragment):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Depends on how you are "changing" your fragment. If you `add` it and then popBack then `onResume` won't be called. Probably you're `replacing` fragments and on popBack you get `onResume` callback fired

Answer (score 4):

I use in my activity - **KOTLIN**

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
                val f = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

                if (f?.tag == "MyFragment")
                {
                    //doSomething
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

What i do in child fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   ParentFragment pf = (ParentFragment) this.getParentFragment();
   pf.onResume();
}
```

And then override onResume on ParentFragment

Comment: You should never call lifecycle methods manually, especially inside each other

Comment: @breakline this technique works. Do you have any other way?

Comment: Yes, you should add your own implementation to call because lifecycle methods are also called by the system and if you call lifecycle methods inside each other like this you might (and most likely will) cause later issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the fragment in XML, you can't swap them dynamically.  What happens is they overly, so they events don't fire as one would expect.  The issue is documented in this question. [FragmenManager replace makes overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079992/fragmenmanager-replace-makes-overlay)

Turn middle_fragment into a FrameLayout, and load it like below and your events will fire.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransation().
    add(R.id.middle_fragment, new MiddleFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

Step1: Override the Tabselected method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    try {
    if(MyEventsFragment!=null && tab.getPosition()==3)
    {
        MyEvents.fragmentChanged();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Step 2: Using static method do what you want in your fragment,

```
public static void fragmentChanged()
{
    Toast.makeText(actvity, "Fragment Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onPause()` method works in activity class you can use:

```
public void onDestroyView(){
super.onDestroyView    
}
```

for same purpose..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of [@Gor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022868/2914140) I wrote similar in Kotlin. Place this code in `onCreate()` of an activity. It works for one fragment visible. If you have `ViewPager` with fragments, it will call `ViewPager`'s fragment, not a previous one.

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    supportFragmentManager.fragments.lastOrNull()?.onResume()
}
```

After reading https://medium.com/@elye.project/puzzle-fragment-stack-pop-cause-issue-on-toolbar-8b947c5c07c6 I understood that it would be better in many situations to attach new fragments with `replace`, not `add`. So a need in `onResume` in some  cases will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

for me, the cause was using navGraph to switch between fragments

```
app:navGraph
```

create the fragment like this (in Kotlin) and then all the lifecycle functions get called

```
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple **can't** add a fragment to a fragment. This needs to happen in the FragmentActivity. I assume you are creating the LoginFragment in a FragmentActivity, so in order to get this working you need to add the HomeFragment via the FragmentActivity when the login closes.

The general point is that you need a FragmentActivity class from where you add each Fragment to the FragmentManager.  It is **not possible** to do this inside a Fragment class.

Comment: Yes they are inside a fragment activity.

Comment: if fragments are added dynamically then you can add as many fragment as you want to a fragment but not to the ones defined in xml<fragment > tag

Comment: Nested fragments are now fully supported by AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps, and you shall get the needed answer**

1- For both fragments, create a new abstract parent one.
2- Add a custom abstract method that should be implemented by both of them.
3- Call it from the current instance before replacing with the second one.

Comment: How does it help in situation when a user returns from fragment 2 to fragment 1?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ft.replace` should trigger the onPause (of the replaced fragment) and onResume (of the replacing fragment).

I do notice that your code inflates `login_fragment` on the home fragment, and also doesn't return the views in the onCreateView. If these are typos, can you show how these fragments are being called from within your activity?

Comment: This is not an answered, what if "add" is must for someone's design?!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible override methods guaranteed to be called when a fragment appears/disappears.

oncreateview/ondestroyview - this is called whenever the fragment visibility changes

onpause/onresume - called when the app is closed by external or you use fragment replace

If you wish to create a hook as I did so you can by notified whenever a fragment is closed and catch either situation without creating a duplicate call as sometimes both could be called.

try extending the fragment class and add a boolean flag in both overrides so you catch the open and close for sure without duplicating

Answer (score 0):

kotlin

```
requireFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            val fragments: List<Fragment> = requireFragmentManager().fragments
            if (fragments.isNotEmpty() && fragments[fragments.size - 1] is YOUR_FRAGMENT) {
                //todo if fragment visible
            } else {
                //todo if fragment invisible
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

While creating a fragment transaction, make sure to add the following code.

```
// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment, 
// and add the transaction to the back stack 
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment); 
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Also make sure, to commit the transaction after adding it to backstack