# FragmentTransaction replace causes overlay

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I read this [FragmenManager replace makes overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079992/fragmenmanager-replace-makes-overlay) and the solution which stated the problem was due to defining the fragment statically in the xml.  I have the same problem, but I did not define my fragment statically, I use a framelayout and the fragment manager to pop in and out my DYNAMICALLY created fragments using support fragment transactions.  Here is my scenario:

Activity 1 has a framelayout called "content" in its xml.

1. fragment X is created and replaces framelayout "content".
2. When a listview item in fragment X is clicked, add fragment Y to the backstack.  "content", which shows fragment X, is replaced with fragment Y.
3. When a button in fragment Y is clicked, fragment Z is added to the backstack.  "content", which shows fragment Y, is replaced with fragment Z.
4. Clicking a button in fragment Z pops the backstack and replaces "content" with a new instance of fragment Y.

These steps work as expected, except after, when I press back to reach fragment X, click on a listview item, and do step 3 again.  Instead of fragment Z replacing fragment Y like earlier, it overlays it.  Why is this happening and how do I resolve it?  Thanks

Code for step 2:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("y_screen");
ft = ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentY.newInstance(qTitle, qDetails, qObjectID));
ft.commit();
```

Code for step 3:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("z_screen");
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentZ.newInstance(questionTitle, questionDetails,
                                                     qObjectID));
ft.commit();
```

Code for step 4:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
fm.popBackStack();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentY.newInstance(questionTitle, questionDetails,    
                                                     qid));
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: how is it possible to have a fragment overlay another when I only use ft.replace, not add?