# onResume() is not working properly in Fragments?

Tags: java, android

I am working on Fragments,so here I have three fragments in My view pager

So here I am using `onResume()` method in my first fragment, so when I swipe from one fragment to another and I came back to first fragment My `onResume` Method is not working

So any one give the solutions guys

Comment: viewpager keeps by default the previous and next fragments in memory so onResume will not get called

Comment: there is no solution for this

Comment: Please try to explain your problem a bit more , I guess something is losing up because of language barrier.

Comment: Fragment's onResume() is strongly bound to activity's onResume(). if activity's onResume() is called only then fragment's onResume() is called.

Comment: Implement View pager's onTabSelected() method and handle there

Answer (score 1):

The `fragment's` `onResume()` or `onPause()` will be called only when the `Activities` `onResume()` or `onPause()` is called. They are tightly coupled to the `Activity`. Check  [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252923/3736955).

Also it may get called few times when you are on `fragment` screen. In your case since your `viewpager` is inside `Activity`, `fragment onResume()` may not get called when you swipe to that `fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way `ViewPager` keeps `Fragment`s in memory.  If the `Fragment` is scrolled more than the offscreen page limit (set via `.setOffscreenPageLimit()`), it should be removed from memory and reinstantiated when it's reloaded (which, IIRC, may not be guaranteed to be when it comes back onscreen).

To run fragment-specific code when a page is selected, you can try something like the following:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        final MyFragment fragment = mAdapter.getFragment(position);
        fragment.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem myself.

Add a `tabListener` to your viewpager first.
In the `onTabSelected` method, create an instance of your selected fragment and call `onResume()`.

```
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    mContent.setUserVisibleHint(false);
                    mContent.onPause();
                    mContent = mAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition());
                    mContent.setUserVisibleHint(true);
                    mContent.onResume();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                }
            };
```

Here, `mContent` is the currently selected fragment, and `mAdapter` is the viewpager's adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment (with ViewPager) use setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibileToUser) instead onResume():

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
    refresh();
} else {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436045/onresume-not-called-in-fragment-using-tablayout-and-viewpager