# TabLayout - How to load a fragment on tab press only

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout, sceneform

I'm using a ViewPager with a TabLayout. One of the tabs is an ArFragment.
When the Activity starts, TabLayout iterates over each of the tabs and initializes them, causing ArFragment to request camera permission even when the appropriate tab is not pressed.

After an extensive search I've come to the conclusion that Sceneform doesn't allow control over camera permission request timing, so the only other option is to control the tab loading times.

How do I make TabLayout not load a specific tab on init (but still remember it's instance when changing tabs after that)?

To the matter at hand:
I've tried to use addOnTabSelectedListener, but not sure exactly how to go on with it:

```
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object :
        TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            when(tab.position) {
                // First Tab
                0 -> return

                // AR
                1 -> // I want to create a new ARFragment() and inflate it to this tab's fragment container. But how?
            }
        }
    })
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you just initialize this feature when the fragment becomes visible? See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436045/onresume-not-called-in-fragment-using-tablayout-and-viewpager/59453872#59453872

Comment: I've considered it, but the problem is that I must inflate the fragment's layout to the ViewGroup, which I can only do (correct me if I'm wrong) in the OnCreateView function. My initial problem is that OnCreateView is only called once when the whole TabLayout is initialized, and I want it to be called on tab press.

Comment: Then what if you use this tab fragment as a container for another fragment that is just launched when you click the tab?

Comment: Well that's exactly the case. Each tab is a fragment. My ViewPager inherits from FragmentPagerAdapter, and by using tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager) the pager's 'getItem(position)' function which return a fragment is being called. Initially I set this function to return my fragment when the appropriate position was requested, but apparently this function is only called once - on TabLayout init.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got me correctly. I was talking about starting a fragment from your tab fragment. Your tab fragment might already have been created by your viewpager. But only when it becomes visible you navigate to another fragment within that tab fragment that finally shows your AR fragment (and requests the required permissions)

Comment: I think I understand, I'll give it a go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
class ArFragment : ... {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ar, container, false)
    }
    
    ovveride fun onResume() {
      // init variables
      // init views
    }
}

class MyViewPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager,private val noOfTabs: Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
   .......
   .......
}
```

Perform all your fragment related works in `onResume()` of the fragment and make sure to extend `FragmetnPagerAdapter` in your ViewPager adapter class with the `behavior=BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`. You can check the above code snippet.

Let me know if you face any issues.