# How to use Android Application global SharedPreference in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have a 'SharedPreference' in my Android Application class file like this :

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static Context context;
    public static SharedPreferences preference;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   }
}
```

I put values to preference from a long running background service, so when I want to update my fragment content on fragment resume from this preference, in first load of activity and fragment everything is OK, but when I switch fragments, my fragment contents doesn't get updated. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

To get the instance of your preference in any fragment you can use following code.

```
((App)getActivity().getApplication()).preference
```

I can see that your preference refrence is declared as static. If there is no particular reason to keep it static you can remove the static modifier.

Comment: I set preference field static to access it from anywhere in my application without creating instance from App class. I want to read preference data in Background Services, Activities, Fragments and BroadcastReceivers. I am in trouble only by Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this answer [Fragment onResume() not called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252923/5118375) your `onResume()` is not called when the fragment is swapped and recreated again.

I suggest you try to update your data in `onCreateView()`.
You can access the shared preferences from the fragment using `getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)`