# How to update data on fragment resume

Tags: android, fragment, detach

I want to update the data on my android fragment when it's loaded on top of the stack or when the application is resumed or on some button click event. I tried using attach and detach method but its not working. I also tried `onbackstackchangedlistener()` but no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to get the onResume working as Shylendra answers here is how one could handle it.

Just put this code inside

> onResume()

Here is an example for when you want to update your listview when you return to your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (allowRefresh)
    {
        allowRefresh = false;
        myListView = db.load_apps();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As he answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326155/fragment-onresume-onpause-is-not-called-on-backstack)

The fragments `onResume()` or `onPause()` will be called only when the Activities `onResume()` or `onPause()` is called.
They are tightly coupled to the `Activity`.

Read the [Handling the Fragment Lifecycle section of this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).