# Which event is called when a fragment appears again from the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have one activity with 2 fragment: **Fragment1** and **Fragment2**.

After click one item from my RecyclerView I call Fragment2 with the following line:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frmFragmentItem,detailsFragment);
```

When the user closes Fragment2 (BackButton or Close button), Fragment1 appears again on the screen.

**WHAT I NEED:**

Which is the event that is called when the instance of Fragment1 appears again in the screen?

After revise the following life cycle of the fragment, I thought that may be was **onCreateView()** or **onResume()** but is not (because the breakpoint didn't stop).

[image]

**THE QUESTION:**

So, could you tell me which event is called when Fragment1 appears again the screen (The instance of the fragment has already created)

**ANOTHER POSSIBILITY?**

Also I thought to use startActivityForResult & onActivityResult, but I don't know how to use it if I call Fragment2 with the following lines:

```
Fragment2 detailsFragment = new Fragment2 ();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frmFragmentItem,detailsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Ascorbin answer, I could implement what he said:

> What you can do is add a listener to the fragment backstack and get informed when fragment 1 is popped from the backstack

**I think is important to show how to implement the solution, because on internet there isn't information about it.**

For the implementation, you have to do:

**1.**

Your activity that contains your fragment, has to implement **OnBackStackChangedListener** like the code below

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
```

**2.**

Then, in your activity you have to override the listener so:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    if(fragment1 != null)
        fragment1.doTheAction();
}
```

So, when the user comes back from Fragment2 to Fragment1 again, the method onBackStackChanged will be called and Fragment1 will execute *doTheAction* function.

Finally, when Fragment1 starts Fragment2 I do in my activity the following code:

```
 Fragment2 secondFragment= new Fragment2();
 android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frmFragmentItem,secondFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("FRAGMENT_1");
 getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

After that, you don't need to do anything else.

**Nice coding!**

Answer (score 2):

None of the fragment's lifecycle events will be called, unfortunately, as [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326155/fragment-onresume-onpause-is-not-called-on-backstack).

`startActivityForResult` won't help you when dealing with `Fragment`s.

What you can do is [add a listener to the fragment backstack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#addOnBackStackChangedListener(android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener)) and get informed when `fragment 1` is  popped from the backstack. 
You might do that in your `Activity`, keep references of your `Fragment`(s), then call some method on the `Fragment` to inform it that it has "re-appeared".

Comment: I know what you mean and I think that you are right, but Could you explain me a little more about how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: ,Will you give me the example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frmFragmentItem,detailsFragment);
```

will not remove the fragment from container. It still resides in the container that is why you are not receiving the callbacks.

If you use,

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frmFragmentItem,detailsFragment);
```

the previous fragment will be removed from container and you will receive the proper callbacks as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread is very old but for people that keep searching about that, you can just override the `onResume` function from the fragment.

This function is called each time the fragment appears on the user's screen (entering as well as re-entering from forward fragment)